# Black screen during and after watching video

Tags: windows-10, video, graphics-card, flash, amd-radeon

**Cause:** I have a problem with my new Windows 10 PC that during streaming a video the entire screen goes black at a random point during the video. This occurred multiple times when watching a trailer using the Steam application (full screen) and also in Microsoft Edge when streaming an Adobe Flash video (not full screen). It doesn't seem to be exactly reproducible, watching the same video again doesn't always crash it. This hasn't occurred on YouTube (HTML5 video) in Firefox (yet?).

**Effect:** The sound continues but the screen goes black. Only the cursor is still visible. Even key-combinations like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (Lock user) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> (Change desktop) doesn't unblock the screen. It seems like the computer is still working because the cursor changes to the resize cursor or select cursor at certain positions on the screen. Switching the monitor off and on again doesn't help either. After hibernating the computer (using the power button) the same effect is present but now the screen is grey instead of black. The only way I found to get rid of this effect is to completely restart the PC.

**SW-Versions:** I have the newest version of Windows 10 (at the time of this writing, 06.06.2016 14:30), the newest version of Flash (21.0.0.242), the newest version of Edge (25.10586.0.0 / 13.10586), the newest version of Steam (Package version 1461972496) and Radeon Software Version 15.11 (Graphics Chipset: AMD Radeon (TM) R9 390 Series).

Any ideas how to preferably solve the problem permanently or just how to "snap out of it" when it does occur?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should probably check what video card is your machine using. If it is a new Win 10 PC then there is an additional GPU unit build-in the CPU (at least in all Intel based CPU's). Make sure that the GPU driver for the integrated video is properly installed.

Comment: @alljamin Thanks for the suggestion. I do have a Intel i7 6700k and tried downloading the graphics drivers but the installation failed ("This computer does not meet the minimum requirements for installing the software." but I double checked all requirements and I don't understand why it doesn't work). The Intel Driver Update Utility doesn't find anything to install either. I might try to just deactivate the CPU graphics and only use the external card.

Comment: Can you specify the model of your motherboard? So I can point you to the right direction in driver search.

Comment: Go to [Asus official website](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/MAXIMUS-VIII-HERO/HelpDesk_Download/) and choose your OS and then download and install chipset and VGA drivers. Just for the sake of it you might also want to start installation under Administrator profile - by choosing ``Run as Administrator``.

Comment: I managed to install the chipset drivers and did a restart but the "Intel Graphics Accelerator Driver" gives the same error message as the one I downloaded from Intel's website (I ran the AsusSetup.exe in the root folder and x64 folder and ran the Setup.exe in the x64 folder, all as admin). I tried both versions (20.19.15.4285 and 10.18.15.4274), both gave the same result. I can see if it works better now just with the chipset drivers installed.

Comment: When you go to ``Device manager`` do you see Intel graphics card installed (under Display adapters section) or ``Microsoft Basic Display Adapter``?

Comment: Only the AMD Radeon card is shown under Display adapters. In the category Processors the correct CPU was detected but is shown 8 times (one per thread?). Right-click -> Update Driver Software says the best version is already installed. Under System devices there is a `Microsoft Basic Display Driver` and says the device is working properly but the manufacturer is `(Standard display types)`. This also says the best driver software is already installed when I asked it to do an update.

Comment: Then you need to update the ``Microsoft Basic Display adapter`` driver manually.
Right click on this display adapter->``Properties->Driver->Update Driver...->Browse my computer for driver software->Browse``
Choose the location to where you have downloaded the driver and press Okay.

Comment: It still says the best drivers are already installed when selecting any of the downloaded folders (and "Include Subfolders" is selected). BTW I don't have a `Microsoft Basic Display ADAPTER` but a `Microsoft Basic Display DRIVER`. Not sure if it's the same thing...